# Using url with parameters to download image from internet for Android?

Tags: java, android

Using **URL with parameters** to download image from internet for Android???

This code is work,but I don't want that,I want to use a URL with parameters to download image.(ex:**URL=http://yahoo.com/record?ProductID=1**)

How to change this code?please.

```
bmp = this.GetNetBitmap("http://avatar.csdn.net/B/D/5/1_redoffice.jpg");

public Bitmap GetNetBitmap(String url){
URL imageUrl = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try{
imageUrl = new URL(url);
}
catch(MalformedURLException e){
Log.e("DownloadTimerTask", e.getMessage());
}
try{ HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); is.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
Log.e("DownloadTimerTask", e.getMessage());
}
return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write a function is similar lines as below :

```
public static Drawable imageFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource();` to convert `Drawable` to `BitMap` if you desire.